# Python tree implementation not showing correct path

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

I tried implementing the following code. But according to logic, the path output for node "a" to "d" is displayed None, though the path can be "a,c,d".I want to apply BFS, DFS,etc search algorithms, but before that I need to implement the tree first-which is not happening.

```
graph = { "a" : ["c"],
          "b" : ["c", "e"],
          "c" : ["a", "b", "d", "e"],
          "d" : ["c"],
          "e" : ["c", "b"],
          "f" : []
            }  
def find_path(graph, start, end, path =[]): 
  path = path + [start] 
  if start == end: 
    return path 
  for node in graph[start]: 
    if node not in path: 
      newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path) 
      if newpath:  
         return newpath 
      return None

print(find_path(graph, 'a', 'd'))
```

Comment: are `graph` leafs considered to be a lists only?

Comment: yes,I'm using lists to store the child nodes.

Comment: what's the maximum depth level?

Comment: Here is the similar and better approach: https://github.com/Sajjadmanal/Python-Projects/blob/master/Programs/BFS_treetraversal

https://github.com/Sajjadmanal/Python-Projects/blob/master/Programs/DFS_treetraversal

Comment: Max. level is leaf node.

Comment: The reference provided works well. Thanks. But I have a doubt, while defining the nodes, left .left means Level 2 right?  " root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)", But what if I have large level values? should I go like left.left.left.right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return None before you have checked all connected nodes.

```
graph = { "a" : ["c"],
          "b" : ["c", "e"],
          "c" : ["a", "b", "d", "e"],
          "d" : ["c"],
          "e" : ["c", "b"],
          "f" : []
            }

def find_path(graph, start, end, path =[]):
  print(f'start={start}, end={end}, path={path}, call find_path')
  path = path + [start]
  print(f'start={start}, end={end}, path={path}, append start to path')
  if start == end:
    return path
  for node in graph[start]:
    if node not in path:
      newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
      if newpath:
         return newpath
      # return None <---- You return to early

print(find_path(graph, 'a', 'd'))
>>> ['a', 'c', 'd']
```

---

those are your steps without `return None` (finds ['a', 'c', 'd'])

```
start=a, end=d, path=[], call find_path
start=a, end=d, path=['a'], append start to path
start=c, end=d, path=['a'], call find_path
start=c, end=d, path=['a', 'c'], append start to path
start=b, end=d, path=['a', 'c'], call find_path
start=b, end=d, path=['a', 'c', 'b'], append start to path
start=e, end=d, path=['a', 'c', 'b'], call find_path
start=e, end=d, path=['a', 'c', 'b', 'e'], append start to path
start=d, end=d, path=['a', 'c'], call find_path
start=d, end=d, path=['a', 'c', 'd'], append start to path
```

and those are your steps with it (finds no route)

```
start=a, end=d, path=[], call find_path
start=a, end=d, path=['a'], append start to path
start=c, end=d, path=['a'], call find_path
start=c, end=d, path=['a', 'c'], append start to path
start=b, end=d, path=['a', 'c'], call find_path
start=b, end=d, path=['a', 'c', 'b'], append start to path
start=e, end=d, path=['a', 'c', 'b'], call find_path
start=e, end=d, path=['a', 'c', 'b', 'e'], append start to path
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael! It works perfectly fine, but I have a doubt, in the solution with "return None", at line 9, it changes from ['a', 'c', 'b', 'e'] to ['a', 'c']?

Comment: semms ok to me. It is just another "branch". It starts with `a, c`. From there it can go either to `a, c, b`,`a, c, d` or `a, c, e`. `a, c, b` is tried first. From there it can go to `a, c, b, e` but no further. It falls back to `a, c` and goes to `a, c, d` instead.

Comment: ohh okay , got that! Thanks. So , can I implement BFS/DFS or any algorithm on it? It won't get affected right?

Comment: Also, I just want to print the last iteration, I tried de-indenting, but it's showing me wrong indentation. Could you help?

Comment: what you have now is already depth first.  What exactly do you want to print? The path is returned by your function alreay

Comment: I want to define 3 functions, 1 that returns Breadth first search, 2nd Depth First(which you said is already displayed, and 3rd for Hill climbing.

Comment: so Breadth first would be if you first check all of you "base" nodes. Then all of their children then there grandchildren etc. If there are multiple paths between your start and end node the results may be different (I guess this is what you want to print). As far as I know Hill climbing is an algorithm to find local extreme values using some kind of slope tho choose the next node. I'm not quite sure if this algorithm can be used to find paths between nodes (what would the slope be?)

Comment: Okay, no problem I'll research more on Hill climbing. Can you explain how the DFS idea works here? As according to it, you expand children's grandchildren and so on, till you reach the depth of leftmost tree, then go right and repeat. So how is it working here?     "Also, for a->e, as per DFS it should display a->c->e, but the above program displays a->c->b->e?

Comment: actually for DFS a->c->b->e seems right to me. It discovers the grandchildren of c (namely a->c->b->e) before it discovers all of the  its children (a->c->e). Thats exactly how DFS works. On contrary BFS would discover a->c->e first. Take a look at the figure here: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/Justsearch.html

Comment: Okay, got that. Thanks